# Como gerar números aleatórios para Sorteio?

Tags: php, java, c#, python, random

Preciso gerar números para uma promoção, esses números devem ir de 0 a 99999.

Como posso fazer para distribuir esses números de forma aleatória e equitativa, sem repetir números já distribuídos?

Comment: vc precisa de apenas um número?

Comment: você precisa escolher uma linguagem, ou você quer que gere em todas as linguagens das tags?

Comment: @RicardoPontual não preciso de uma linguagem específica, gostaria apenas de ver uma abordagem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Em Python você pode usar [randint](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint). Ex:

```
from random import randint
numero = randint(0, 99999)
```

Caso você precise gerar mais de um número, e que esses sejam únicos, você pode fazer um loop e armazenar esses números em uma lista.

```
qtd_pessoas = 10
lista_numeros = []
for pessoa in range(qtd_pessoas):
    if numero not in lista_numeros:
        lista_numeros.append(numero)
```

Caso você tenha que gerar esses números em execuções diferentes ao invés de gerar todos na mesma execução, vai ser necessário utilizar algum meio de armazenamento, podendo ser desde um banco de dados, até um simples arquivo de texto. Utilizando um arquivo de texto, por exemplo, você teria que:

1. Ler o arquivo.
2. Gerar uma lista com os números que estão nesse arquivo.
3. Gerar um número aleatório e verificar se ele não está na lista gerada no passo 2.
4. Caso ele não esteja nessa lista, é adicionado ao arquivo e o programa encerra. Caso esteja na lista, você repete o passo 2.

Abaixo um exemplo utilizando randint, [manipulação de arquivos](http://www.programeempython.com.br/blog/manipulando-arquivos-com-), splitlines, while e break.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
from random import randint

ARQUIVO = 'numeros.txt'

# Caso o arquivo seja criado manualmente, essa parte é descenessária.
if ARQUIVO not in os.listdir():
    # O arquivo não existe, então é necessário cria-lo.
    with open(ARQUIVO, 'w') as arq:
        arq.write('')

# O bloco abaixo vai ler o arquivo e vai adicionar os números salvos
# na lista_numeros
with open(ARQUIVO, 'r') as arq:
    lista_numeros = arq.read()
    lista_numeros = lista_numeros.splitlines()

# Criamos um loop infinito, que vai ser executado que um números que não
# esteja na lista seja criado, e seja executada a instrução "break"
while True:
    numero = str(randint(0, 9999)) # Vamos trabalhar com string na hora de gravar.
    if numero not in lista_numeros:
        with open(ARQUIVO, 'a') as arq:
            arq.write(numero + '\n')
            print(numero)
            break
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 7):

Pode usar a função `rand`.

```
<?php
echo rand(0, 99999);

?>
```

Answer (score 6):

Para uma solução "lógica" como indicada nas TAGs, adaptei uma fórmula para gerar números aleatórios que tinha no manual da antiga calculadora científica **HP 35E** (década de 80).

Abaixo exponho a lógica para quem se interessar em testar em qualquer linguagem:

```
Semente = 0,283746479248234
```

Informe ou gere um número **entre 0 e 1 exclusive**. Para mudar dinamicamente a semente pode ser feito "bem bolado" usando, por exemplo, o valor numérico das Horas, Minutos e Segundos de forma que gere um valor entre 0 e 1. Este valor pode ser conferido se resultou em 0 ou 1 para ser gerado novamente, uma vez que este valor deve estar "entre" estes dois valores.

```
 Semente = 999 x Semente - INT(999 x Semente)
```

Neste momento foi gerado o novo valor entre 0 e 1 para a semente, ou seja, refazendo o processo que estou descrevendo, outro número será sorteado, apesar de poder ocorrer repetições (repetições que podem ser tratadas conforme as respostas anteriores). Esta função INT deve pegar a parte inteira "sem arredondamentos", senão pegue diretamente a parte fracionária do resultado da multiplicação.

```
  Inteiro_mínimo = 0

  Inteiro_máximo = 99999
```

Aqui são informados os valores do intervalo dos números inteiros desejados

```
  Inteiro_máximo = Inteiro_máximo + 1
```

Esta é uma adaptação que fiz, pois como a equação não gera o valor 1, nunca será obtido o resultado 99999, como será pego o valor inteiro do resultado, observando que a parte inteira gerada pela função INT não deve ser arredondada, ao somar 1 isso irá incluir o valor 99999 no sorteio como desejado.

```
  Numero_sorteado = INT( semente x Inteiro_máximo + Inteiro mínimo)
```

A equação "semente x Inteiro_máximo" nunca irá gerar o valor 0, porém, irá gerar valores Reais maiores que zero e menores que 999, ou seja, quando resultar em valores menores do que 1, a função INT (sem arredondar) irá resultar no valor 0.

A HP informou na época que tal procedimento gera uma função matemática que gera pouca repetição. Na época eu chaguei a gerar vários jogos com esse recurso, já que não existia uma tecla RANDOM, e realmente observei tal fato. Espero ter contribuído.

Answer (score 5):

Em Java:

```
Random random = new Random();
random.nextInt(100000);
```